How to use Physics2D.OverlapBox to check for an instance of a GameObject at a position. (Unity 2D)
I am working on a map generator and need to check if a room is present at a position to demine weather a room can be spawned.
The method currently reads
    private void CreateRoom(GameObject room, Vector3 pos)
    {

        Collider2D roomsAtSpawnPoint = Physics2D.OverlapBox(pos, new Vector2(1f, 1f), 0f, roomLayer);

        if (roomsAtSpawnPoint == null)
        {
            GameObject room_ = Instantiate(room, pos, Quaternion.identity);
            roomsAtSpawnPoint = null;
        }

    }

The code currently runs and spawns rooms successfully but it is still spawning rooms on top of other rooms.

depends what "roomLayer" actually is, as well as Im slightly surprised that 0f is recognised as a quaternion but ive not tried it

the rooms layer is set up to detect only rooms which the "room" game object is on, also I tried changing the 0f to a Quaternion but I got a error asking for a float instead.

Ok I missed it was 2d, so, thats an angle, that makes some sense, although, maybe it hates 0?  How have you defined the layermask?

I defined the layer mask with "[SerializeField] LayerMask roomLayer;" and assigned it in the editor to a layer "Rooms" that the rooms are a part of. I tried setting the angle to 1 and 90, still doesn't work.

OK, a lot of people create a "layer" and set it to be say "rooms" .. and of course thats a mask for anything but rooms - wanted to check. .

The problem might be that you are only checking a 1 by 1 area around the position you are trying to create the room. If the room is larger than one unit long or wide, then the 1 by 1 area around the center of the room might not contain the collider of the other room in it but the 2 rooms may still intersect. This can be fixed by increasing the area of the overlap box to match the area of the room.
Another issue that might be causing the CreateRoom function not to work is if the rooms do not have the correct coliders or are not in the roomLayer layer.
